# How to do "if Single Click" instead of "if MouseDown" in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to do a single click and have it not repeat the function if my mouse is still down if that makes any sense.

Currently I have it:

```
if (mouseDown)
{
     avatar.moveABit( 0, -2);
     sfxSoundChannel = moveSound.play();
}
```

and if I keep my Mouse Down it keeps repeating that. I want it to only work with a single click, and have to keep tapping to do it instead of leaving the mouse down.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want

```
MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICK
```

I would add an event listener on the object that is being clicked to listen for the click, and on the click run the handler function which would contain your move and soundplay code.

See [this documentation](http://flashwonderland.com/mouse-control/actionscript-mouse-events-introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need `MouseEvent.CLICK` like so:

```
//Create a function (which moves avatar) to be called on mouse click
function moveAvatar(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    avatar.moveABit( 0, -2);
    sfxSoundChannel = moveSound.play();
}
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, moveAvatar); //add mouse click event listener
```

EDIT: `moveABit` should not be using `ENTER_FRAME` event.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood it correctly, maybe we'll need more of your code to understand what you really want.
I'm assuming that you're using some kind of loop (setInterval, Event.ENTER_FRAME) to check if the mouse button is down or not. If you are, I think you should change that to only fire inside a function like this:

```
    function OnMouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        avatar.moveABit( 0, -2);
        sfxSoundChannel = moveSound.play();
    }
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, OnMouseDownHandler, false, 0, true);
```

If you use MouseEvent.CLICK event the OnMouseDownHandler Method will be fired only when you release the mouse button, using MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN will behave more like a "Tap".